# Distributed Transcations, DTCPING, How to set NetBIOS

Tags: c#, msdtc, distributed-transactions, netbios

I'm the Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator to write to two different databases on separate servers that are not on the same network. When I attempt to execute the code inside a C# TransactionScope, I get the following error:

"Communication with the underlying transaction manager has failed."

I'm using the DTCPing.exe tool to attempt to ping the remove server to see why I get this error.

However, I'm being told I need to only using the NetBIOS name of the remote computer instead of its IP address.  However, I'm not sure how to accomplish this, given that my two machines are on separate networks.

NOTE - I've also temporarily disabled the windows firewall on both machines.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but I believe you just add an entry to your `hosts` file.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc751132.aspx